# My website is forwarding to /public_html without reason

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, forwarding

Some time ago i wanted to my website forwards from http:// to https://
I edited .htaccess file with some code, but it did'nt work and I deleted .htaccess.
Now, without .htaccess file, it redirects automatically to /public_html/ folder. Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file with sample rewrites and check if it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```